# unable to locate element by XPATH on Tripadvisor

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I don't know how to click on this image, I tried many things but it doesn't work. That says the XPATH is wrong.
what I want to click :
[image]

[image]

my code :

```py
# TripAdvisor
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.fr/")
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-reject-all-handler"]').click()
time.sleep(1.5)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

if choices == "r":
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#lithium-root > main > div.cBOoN > div.rGQXC._T.ivvQp > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > a').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/form/input[1]').send_keys(city)
    time.sleep(0.75)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="typeahead_results"]/a[1]').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-reject-all-handler"]').click()
    except:
        pass


    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="component_48"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/label').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="component_36"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[2]/span').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="component_48"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/label').click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="component_48"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/label').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="component_2"]/div/div[1]/div/span/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]/a').click()
```

I also tried with coordinates but that don't work.
Thank you for anyone who helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to improve your locators and use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits instead of `driver.implicitly_wait`.
the following code works:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.fr/"

driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-test-target='nav-links']//a[contains(@href,'Restaurants')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-test-attribute*='RESTAURANTS'] input[type='search']"))).send_keys("Paris")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#typeahead_results a[href*='Restaurants']"))).click()
time.sleep(1)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='checkbox_5']"))).click()
time.sleep(4)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Supprimer tous les filtres')]"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='checkbox_3']"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='checkbox_4']"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'Review-')]//div[contains(@class,'carousel')]//span[@class]"))).click()
```

Comment: Ok it work if the city is Paris but i want to choose the city as i want ... do you have any ideas to do that ?

Comment: And that dont pick me the first picture of the list :/

Comment: I tried other Cities like Nice or Cannes and it worked perfectly.

Comment: mmmhhhh ok but i have a last probleme, i want to click one by one the frame on tripadvisor you think this is possible ?

Comment: bcs actually it's looks like it take a random frame/image from the page.

Comment: I believe any question can be resolved, however this will be a new question while I think the original question is answered. If you agree with that please accept this answer and if you have more questions please ask new question for that. Also, when you asking a new question it will appear at the top of the feed while this question now is deep down in the feed.

Answer (score 0):

instead of digging through divs, you could try looping through elements that match a more specific xpath, like this

```
//a[contains(@href,"html")]//descendant::img[contains(@src,"https://media-cdn")]
```

Comment: that dont work :/